# firebase Google Cloud storage download URL has folder name which becomes file name

Tags: html, google-chrome, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

We are using Firebase Google Cloud Storage Bucket to store our files.

When the logged in user wants the download the file kept inside certain folder 
Eg: 123/admin/1469611803143/123.xlsx

The url generated will be 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MYWEBSITE.appspot.com/o/123%2Fadmin%2F1469611803143%2F123.xlsx?alt=media&token=whatever_alpa_numeric_token

As I download this file the file name will be **123%2Fadmin%2F1469611803143%2F123.xlsx**

and not **123.xlsx**

We have tried using **download attribute** to change the file name

but this did not change the file name to 123.xlsx

Please HELP

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty new with firebase but I achieved this with the following code :

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var child = storageRef.child("your path");
var uploadTask = child.put(<file>);

uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
function(snapshot){
// HANDLE TASK PROGRESS
},
function(error){
// HANDLE ERROR
},
function(){
// UPLOAD SUCCESSFULL
  var newMetadata = {
    contentDisposition : "attachment; filename=" + fileName
  }
  child.updateMetadata(newMetadata)
})
```

Comment: Superbe! Works perfectly

Comment: Setting the `contentDisposition` metadata is the right way to do this. One note: that metadata field does not show up in the Firebase storage web console. You can see it with gsutil though.

Answer (score 2):

This is (fortunately or unfortunately) intended behavior. Technically, files in Firebase Storage are stored with the full path (so `123%2Fadmin%2F1469611803143%2F123.xlsx` is actually the file name--the slashes and percent escaping are part of the name, and are only represented as path separators in the UI), which is how we get this behavior.

We're likely to modify how downloads work in the future (in that we'll truncate the name), but we've been busy fixing other bugs and polishing higher priority pieces.

Comment: is there a way to over come it either by setting content-disposition as we are uploading the file or generating signed URLs that include the response-content-disposition

Comment: we are using following code for setting meta data before storage upload
var metadata = {
                 "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                   "Content-Disposition":"attachment;filename="+file.name
             };
But this meta data is not getting set..
How are we supposed to set the Content-Disposition meta data with filename
Will setting this work?

Comment: Please create a new question and include errors, etc. It's hard for us to try this out without an example, and harder to divine what the error is (if any).

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue over 5 years later.  Setting content disposition doesn't appear to have any effect, and frustratingly the "Name" value is exactly what we're wanting.

Comment: After some researching, it looks like `contentDisposition` needs to be specially formatted for Storage.  Reviewing metadata through `gsutil` on files which were uploaded manually through the console, they have an inline disposition: `"inline; filename*=utf-8''YOUR_FILE.ext"`.  Adding this specific `contentDisposition` to file writes makes download names work properly.